# can i make a shape follow a line (not as an animation)

Tags: modeling, objects

[image]I am making an object with a triangular hole in it and I want to know if it is possible for me to just do a circle and somehow have it make a cylinder follow the edge of that hole to make something that looks a bit like a cartoon plunger without me having to make every cylinder by hand and it it is possible how do I do it?

[image: plunger]

[image: cube with hole]

The circle I am talking about in my example is for the diameter of the ring around the edge of the plunger. Basically what I want is, imagine you have pool spaghetti, you know what that is right? The long foam cylinders at most pools. Well, imagine you have one of those. I want to decide the diameter of the circle at each end of it and to have Blender put the edges of the hole at the middle of the circle at the ends of the cylinder and shorten the cylinder to fit on the line.

Steps:

1. take a cube
2. cut a triangular hole in the cube
3. see the edge of the hole
4. tape a cylinder
5. make that cylinder clip through the cube until the line/edge of the hole is at the exact middle of the circle that is at each end of the cylinder
6. make the cylinder the exact same length as the line/edge.

Now I want to be able to just decide the diameter of the cylinder and have it follow the edge/line automatically and exactly rather than having to make it approximatively by hand.

Comment: Hello, do you have a reference image?

Comment: Please clarify with an illustration of some kind. It's not obvious what a 'cartoon plunger' is.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But to me, it's still not clear what you want to do. What do you mean by *"do a circle and somehow have it make a cylinder follow the edge of that hole to make something that looks a bit like a cartoon plunger"*? Do you want to turn the triangle hole into a cylinder?

Comment: the circle i am talking about in my example is for the diameter of the ring around the edge of the plunger. basically what I want is , imagine you have pool spaghetti, you know what that is right? the long foam cylinders at most pools. well imagine you have one of those, I want to decide the diameter of the circle at each end of it and to have blender put the edges of the hole at the middle of the circle at the ends of the cylinder and shorten the cylinder to  fit on the line. i have no idea if that helps or make it more confusing.

Comment: I understand the example of the pool noodle with different diameters on each end. But the part with the hole ... do you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/a/f23AAuL

Comment: step one take a cube, step two cut a triangular hole in the cube, step three see the edge of the hole, step four tape a cylinder, step five make that cylinder clip through the cube until the line/edge of the hole is at the exact middle of the circle that is at each end of the cylinder, step six make the cylinder the exact same length as the line/edge. now i want to be able to just decide the diameter of the cylinder and have it follow the edge/line automatically and exactly rather then having to make it approximatively by hand.

Comment: hello, maybe show a drawing of what you want

Comment: i added the picture to my first post, if you don't see it or still don't understand please tell me

Comment: So, [this is what you want](https://ibb.co/0ZVwHXN), right? What should the corners look like? And should it be fully procedural/non-destructive or is a manual modeling process ok? Here I've duplicated the edges of the hole, converted it into a curve, and extruded it. It looked bad (squashed, non-uniform scale for some reason). So I used a GN modifier to convert the curve into a mesh. That's what you see in the image. Another try was to use a vertex group + GN modifier. But this didn't work well for the corners. It's not one part but 3 parts, like 3 pool noddles placed together.

Comment: The example with the cartoon plunger confused me. You just meant the shape of the handle, right?